Modifiers not working when setting "custom" layout through Desktop Environment
I added a custom keyboard layout, noted, to my system using this guide. In a nutshell, I downloaded a file called custom and put it to the symbols folder:
curl 'https://dl.neo-layout.org/custom_noted' | sudo tee /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom

After that I was able to select it via the means of my desktop environment (KDE on Debian and Gnome by Ubuntu).
The layout comes with many additional modifier keys. Somehow, most of these do not work on letters (e.g. a, s, d, and f). They do, however, work on numbers in the numbers row (e.g. 1, 2, and 3). When activating it by setxkbmap noted everything works as expected.
I tried to disable all other layouts, so noted was the only option selected. Even after a reboot, the problem remained. I tried both Gnome and KDE, so I think it is not related to a bug in those.
How could I get the modifier keys working?

The issue is not due to the desktop environment. When using setxkbmap custom the same issue arises.
The reason for that is that depending on the version of XKB different files have to be used. For older setups, e.g. Debian Bookworm, the custom_noted file must be used. On newer systems, e.g. Debian Testing/Trixie or Ubuntu, the custom_noted_2.39 is the correct file.
Thus, when running
curl 'https://dl.neo-layout.org/custom_noted_2.39' | sudo tee /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom

on Debian Testing/Trixie, everything works like a charm.
